# Issue with deploying applications on Tomcat 7 and 8 from Eclipse Mars EE

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat

I am trying to deploy my Spring application to Tomcat 7 or 8 server (I have both versions installed). Both Tomcat 7 and 8 are installed correctly and are accessible on localhost:8080.
In Eclipse Mars EE I added Tomcat 7 and 8 as servers (see the picture below).

[image]

Then I built the project (Maven), opened the Servers tab in Eclipse and clicked on `No servers are available`. When I want to specify Tomcat 7 (or 8), the field server name is empty (see the picture). The strange thing is that before installing Tomcat 7, this field was filled out and the button Next was available, however in that case there was a message `Unknown server..`.

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how to solve this issue?

**UPDATE:**

I created a new project and refreshed all the settings. Now I am able to see Tomcat 8 in the Servers tab, however when I click Start the following message appears:

[image]

Comment: remove any one of the server good to maintain only one server, and give your `tomcat-home` location while installing the server and install proper `jre's` for your server.

Comment: @subbu royal: I tried to remove Tomcat 7, but the problem was the same. Proper JRE's are also installed.

Comment: right click on any project go to `properties` `project-facets` and select your server, and then right click on any project--> build path(and remove existing jre's)--> add library-->jre system library-->select execution environment--> select jre7 (better to select JavaSE-1.7)

Comment: Check for the local path of your tomcat servers. It might moved or renamed.

Comment: @Ramesh Papaganti. Local path is correct, I checked it.

Comment: @subbu royal: I created a new project. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked. I had to add *jar file when deploying on Server.